# Editing an item's style via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for help regarding how to edit an object's style in a separate CSS file via JS. For example, if I have an object that I style with `#objectid {left: 0%;}` in my CSS file, how would I go about changing that `left` property via JavaScript? I'm aware you can do `object.style.property` but that hasn't been working for me as of late. What's the most efficient/easy method of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using JS on the browser to change a style won't modify the CSS directives contained in the CSS file on the server.  The JS will only modify the style shown in the running browser.  You know that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way:

```
document.getElementById('objectid').style.left = "10%";
```

But if you're worried about efficiency, try not to modify any styles directly using JS... try adding/removing classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the element in the DOM

with pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById('objectid').style.left = '20%'
```

With jQuery

```
$('#objectid').css('left', '20%');
or
$('#objectid').css({'left': '20%'});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct:

```
document.getElementById('thing').style.left="5px"
```

But I believe you need to set the position before it can work, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById('thing').style.position="absolute";
document.getElementById('thing').style.left="5px"
```